# Why is std::rotate faster than this way of doing it?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, stl

```
void rotate(vector <int> &a)
{
    int lastElem = a[a.size()-1];
    
    for(int i=a.size()-1;i>0;i--){
       a[i] = a[i-1];
    }
    
    a[0] = lastElem;
}
```

Versus

```
rotate(a.begin(),a.end()-1,a.end());
```

As far as I can see the algorithm above is O(n) so why is STL way faster(I thought it was linear time as well).

Comment: Is there such a thing as a circular array?  Then rotate could be O(1).

Comment: [ProTip] `int lastElem = a[a.size()-1];` can be replaced with `int lastElem = a.back();`

Comment: STL may use a combination of `memmove` operations?

Comment: `rotate` swaps elements, while you are copying them over. Although in case of `int` it shouldn't matter. Please include your benchmarking code that demonstrates the difference.

Comment: @AdrianMole Seems like that, GCC has special implementation for `std::rotate` called with random access iterators, when value_type is POD. It uses some sort of internal move functions: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/6e885ad3287388192e52e9b524dbaa408507c0a4/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L1294

Comment: not using `vector<>` but my bet is that `a[i]` invokes `vector<>::operator[]` where most likely range check is performed creating major slow down. If true then using direct memory access instead would be much faster. On top of all this rotate could use platform specific fast mem operations instead of C++ generated code you know `memset,memcpy,memmov` ... for example on x86 it might using single `rep movsd` instruction instead of your whole `for` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard library implementation of [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) is likely using a call to `memmove()` for bulk data copying. That would be one reason that it's faster than your hand-written loop.

Since you are only rotating a single element you can replace your loop with a call to [`std::copy_backward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_backward). That will also compile to `memmove()` and provide better performance.

```
void rotate(std::vector<int> &a)
{
    int lastElem = a.back();
    std::copy_backward(a.begin(), a.end() - 1, a.end()); // memmove()
    a.front() = lastElem;
}
```

You can examine the generated assembly [here on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/o6bGcK).

Comment: Note that using the `-O3` is critical on this example (in Compiler Explorer). Indeed,  the code vectorization have a strong impact the resulting performance of this operation and GCC autovectorize the code with `-O3` but not with `-O2` (while `memmove` is vectorized manually).